# Как с помощью DataAdapter заполнить только структуру DataTable без данных?

Tags: c#, .net

В мой класс извне передаётся DataAdapter, мне нужно используя его заполнить только структуру (столбцы с типами данных) DataTable без данных. Следующий код, вопреки моим ожиданиям, подтягивает все данные, которые может вернуть SelectCommand.

```
public class myclass
{
    private readonly DataAdapter da;
    private DataSet ds;
    public myclass (DataAdapter da)
    {
        this.ds = new DataSet();
        this.da = da;
        var dt = ds.Tables.Add("MyTable");
        da.Fill(0, 0, dt);            
    }    
}
```

метаданные по использованному Fill

> ```
>     //
>     // Сводка:
>     //     Добавляет или обновляет строки в объекте System.Data.DataTable для получения
>     //     соответствия строкам в источнике данных, начиная с указанной записи и вплоть
>     //     до заданного максимального количества получаемых записей. 
>     // Параметры:
>     //   startRecord:
>     //     Номер записи (с нуля), с которой необходимо начать.
>     //
>     //   maxRecords:
>     //     Максимальное число извлекаемых записей.
>     //
>     //   dataTables:
>     //     Объект System.Data.DataTable для заполнения из источника данных.
> ```

Каким способом можно заполнить только структуру в DataTable ?

Comment: А просто посмотреть список методов - никак? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/229sz0y5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Пардон, смотрел, но смутили сигнатуры вызова FillSchema .. спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как было указано в комментарии, [статья MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fillschema(v=vs.110).aspx) содержит описание того как это сделать.

```
var dataAdapter = ....
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataTable, SchemaType.Mapped)
```

Если, объект `DbDataAdapter` создавался с описанием параметров связи между таблицами и столбцам (mapping) с помощью свойства `TableMappings` у `DbDataAdapter`, то когда указывается `SchemaType.Mapped` схема исходных данных пытается дополнить схему объекта `DataTable` пропущенными столбцами, на основании данных, которые возвращаются SelectCommand. Если вы хотите принимать только данные, и игнорировать параметры связи, определенные для TableMapping, то стоит использовать `SchemaType.Source`